# how to get the polinomial from partial fractions scilab

Tags: math, fractions, scilab

I am working with the next quotient of polynomials in the scilab software

```
G(s)=B(s)/A(s)=2s^3+5s^2+3s+6/s^3+6s^2+11s+6
```

for this I write the next code
Scilab code:

```
s=%s;  
num=2*s^3+5*s^2+3*s+6;  
den=s^3+6*s^2+11*s+6;  
g=syslin('c',num/den);  
g2=pfss(g);
```

that yields

```
-6/s+3+3/s+1-4/s+2+2
```

But how can I go from the fractions to the transfer function in this software?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for [ss2tf](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/ss2tf.html)? If not, please state what is the result that you wish to obtain in the above example.

Comment: it seems so, let me check, thanks!

Comment: No quite  what Im looking for, but close, as far as I understand the ss2tf expects a system in state space, but at the point wrote this is only a lineal system, then adjusting the code

Comment: g=syslin('c',num/den); gf=tf2ss(g); se=pfss(gf); #(at this point it works but trying to go back)# ss2tf(gf) Invalid type of input argument # 1: Please specify in state space format.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want. You have a fraction like 6/(s+3), what do you want to get from it?

Comment: ok, thats right thats the command Im looking for, but I wasnt able to pass the correct argument, I understand that it expects a state space model, g2 I say so, and then I pretend to get the original G(s), but ss2tf says it is not ss, then which one of the variables should use?

Comment: Of course, the output of pfss is not a state space. It is a bunch of fractions. You can take one of those fractions and create a state-space system from it, like this:  `g21 = tf2ss(g2(1))`  Now if you call `ss2tf(g21)` you get that fraction back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 h=0;for k=1:size(g2), h=h+g2(k);end
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hum, Im trying this this is what I was expected to be

Comment: Hum =), Im trying this!, this is what I was thinking to be,the ss2tf gives me the original partial fractions expansion but that can be my error =(